# R: Manipulating csv scatter data to plot a 3D surface

Tags: r

I'm sure this has been asked before. If you can find a good link I'll happily delete the question but I'm not having any luck with google.

I want to plot some 3D data and searching always leads me back to R (great/simple alternatives would be welcome).

I have a csv file that looks like this...

```
x    y    value
0    0    4.35
0    1    4.23
0    2    4.24
1    0    4.34
1    1    4.23
1    2    4.22
2    0    4.34
2    1    4.22
2    2    4.22
```

All points in the grid are there and unique, so I don't need any interpolation.

I can read it like so...

```
data <- read.table("mydata.csv", header=T, sep=",")
```

I've found a number of 3d plotting functions: persp, wireframe, scatterplot3d, rgl/persp3d, rgl/surface. However haven't had any luck understanding the format they need.

I can output like so...

```
svg("chart.svg", width=4, height=4)
#plot function call(args??)
dev.off()
```

What's the shortest way to rearrange and draw my data as a surface/heightmap and output to SVG (not embedded raster)?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

How's this?

```
my.data <- read.table(text= "x    y    value
0    0    4.35
0    1    4.23
0    2    4.24
1    0    4.34
1    1    4.23
1    2    4.22
2    0    4.34
2    1    4.22
2    2    4.22", header = TRUE)


library(lattice)
wireframe(value ~ x + y, data = my.data, screen = list(z = 70, x = -50))
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks! This works well. Is it easy to join the points? Wireframe will do but ideally I'd like filled polygons. My real data is on the scale of 64x64.

Comment: It seems like the function persp is very similar to what I want, but for that I believe I need to rearrange my data. Eg, create two sequences for x/y and a matrix from my csv to store height values at each x/y.

Comment: I just realized you want a surface diagram, not a scatterplot.

Comment: @jozxyqk Does the `drape` argument to `wireframe` provide an acceptable "fill" for you?

Comment: @CarlWitthoft even better